Need help building a chain out of pairs numbers
I'm working on the AdventOfCode Problem Day 5 (Leaderboard is already full, so asking questions about it is allowed).
The setup:
You get pairs of numbers in the format X|Y where X and Y represent page numbers. One of these pairs is called a rule. That means that X should be printed before Y (i.e. appear in the final list of pages in that order). From there you also receive lists of page numbers to be ordered correctly.
Now, to solve the problem I have to build a full list of all numbers contained in rules, called a ruleset (e.g. [12, 10, 88, 57...]) that obeys all the rules.
To do this, I loop through all the rules and then differentiate 3 cases.
1. None of the numbers are already contained in the full ruleset:
In this case, I just add the pair (X, Y) to the end of the ruleset.
2. One of the numbers is already contained in the ruleset:
In this case, I just add the remaining number in front of, or behind the one already existing in the ruleset.
3. Both of the numbers are already contained, but in the wrong order:
My idea in this case was to just swap the two numbers, which does not work for this example provided by a comment and should be the issue preventing my code to work:
rules: [1,2], [3,4], [4,1]
Using the algorithm above, this leads to a wrong result where the first two rules are not adhered to anymore:
[] -> [1,2] -> [1,2,3,4] -> [4,2,3,1]
Now, I am not sure what to do in case 3 to ensure that all other rules are still met. A part of me feels like there would be a fitting graph theory algorithm here, but I cannot come up with one.
Minimum reproducible example:
rule_chain = []
rules = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,1]]
for rule in rules:
    if rule[0] not in rule_chain and rule[1] not in rule_chain:  # None contained
        rule_chain.append(rule[0])
        rule_chain.append(rule[1])

    elif rule[0] in rule_chain and rule[1] not in rule_chain:    # One contained
        rule_chain.insert(rule_chain.index(rule[0]) + 1, rule[1])

    elif rule[0] not in rule_chain and rule[1] in rule_chain:    # One contained
        rule_chain.insert(rule_chain.index(rule[1]), rule[0])

    else:
        i_0 = rule_chain.index(rule[0])
        i_1 = rule_chain.index(rule[1])
        if i_0 > i_1:                                            # Both contained
            rule_chain[i_1], rule_chain[i_0] = rule_chain[i_0], rule_chain[i_1]
print(rule_chain)


Sum of part 2: <built-in function sum> (after including the missing initialization of wrong_updates. You need to provide a [mre] as a single, complete block of code that can be copied, pasted and run.

Did that, thank you for the advice!

There's a mistake when you construct your rule chain, in the else block.
If both integers are present but in the wrong order then you switch their places.
If they are not adjacent then this can cause other rules which you've already incorporated in your chain to be violated, as it moves these integers over others without checking.
For example, with the rules 1|2 3|4 4|1 your algorithm would produce 4|2|3|1 which is incorrect.

Thank you for that answer! I somehow thought that this was not a problem, but it obviously is. Now, I changed the question to reflect exactly this problem. None of my tries to solve it seemed to be successful and I would appreciate some help.

Try this algorithm.  I'm not going to write the code for you.
Suppose your pages are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  For each page, keep track of which other pages must come before it.  You only care about pages that are in the set 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  The big rule set contains other pages.  You don't care about them for now.
Now there must be some page for which its "pages that have to come before me" set is empty.  Otherwise, you're stuck.  Now there has to be another page for which its "pages that have to come before me" contains at most that first page.  Now there's another page for which its "pages that have to come before me" contains at most those first two pages.  Keep on going until you've done every page.

This was a great idea and my implementation works! Thank you for your help. One other thing: Do you know why this question is being downvoted? I really tried my best to adhere to all rules

What gets down-voted seems random.  I wished that when you downvoted something, you were required to give a reason.

Totally agree. Thank you for the advice again
